# Number of arrangements of the $10\heartsuit|9\heartsuit|8\heartsuit|5\spadesuit|2\clubsuit$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let's say that the original ordering of the cards is $10\heartsuit|9\heartsuit|8\heartsuit|5\spadesuit|2\clubsuit$ and then we shuffle the cards.

I declare these two random variables and I want to calculate the probability of their outcomes:

$X$-number of cards that stayed in the same place after the shuffle.

$Y$-number of the heart suit cards that stayed in the same place after the shuffle.

For $X$ I have looked at this as the probability of picking the right place

$$\small{Pr[X=0]=\frac{D(5)}{5!}, Pr[X=1]=\frac{5*D(4)}{5!}, Pr[X=2]=\frac{{5\choose{2}}*D(3)}{5!}, Pr[X=3]=\frac{{5\choose{3}}*D(2)}{5!},Pr[X=5]=\frac{1}{5!},Pr[X=4]=0}.$$

For $Y$ :
$$Pr[Y=0]=\frac{\small\text{number of derangements of the 3 hearts*}|\{\{5\spadesuit,2\clubsuit\},\{2\clubsuit,5\spadesuit\}\}|}{\text{number of permutations}}=\frac{D(3)\cdot2}{5!}$$

For $Pr[Y=1]$ I'm having trouble counting.

Comment: $X = 4$ is impossible, and thus has probability $0$.

Comment: Yes i agree.Is there anything else that is false?

Comment: You have left off $P(X=0)$.  But, I don't understand your numbers.  Why, say, do you think $P(X=1)=\frac 15$?

Comment: For problems like this, you should always look for consistency checks.  One obvious one is that $\sum_i P(X=i)=1$.  Another is Expected Value. it is easy to compute the expected value of each of these variables...your individual probabilities should be consistent with those computations.

Comment: I said whats the probability of picking the right place for 1 card in 5 places after the shuffle so i thought its $\frac{1}{5}$ but i not sure if i'm covering all of the ordering with that.

Comment: I don't understand that argument.  Start with $P(X=0)$.  To compute that, it might be easiest to take a look at the general notion of [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

Comment: I have looked at it so for 1 card in the correct place there will be $D(4)=9$ for derangements of the other 4 cards and i divide that by all of the permutations of the 5 cards?

Comment: That gives the probability that a single, $\textit {specified}$ card is fixed.  But, really, start with $P(X=0)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107025/discussion-between-user3133165-and-lulu).

Comment: Give my suggestions a try.  Once you get familiar with derangements, the computation is very straight forward.

Comment: Ok so will it be $Pr[X=0]=\frac{D(5)}{5!}=\frac{44}{120}$ and $Pr[X=1]=\frac{5*D(4)}{5!}$ because i need for every card ?

Comment: Both of those are correct.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me now i'm having a bit of trouble calculating $Y$ , I have edited the question with my attempt

Comment: Your answer for $Y=0$ is less than your answer for $X=0$, which makes no sense.  I'd break it into cases.  Count the cases in which no cards are fixed, then allow exactly one of the non-hearts to be fixed, then allow both of the non-hearts to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the probability distribution for $Y$:

Note:  throughout, $!n$ will denote the number of [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) on $n$ letters.

$Y=0\quad $  We have three cases, according to how many of the black cards are fixed.  If $0$ black cards are fixed then there are $!5$ ways to do it. If exactly one black card is fixed then there are $!4$ for each of the two ways to choose the fixed black card.  And if both black cards are fixed then there are $!3$.  Thus $$P(Y=0)=\frac {!5+2\times !4+!3}{5!}=\frac 8{15}$$

$Y=1\quad $  There are $3$ ways to choose the fixed Heart.  For a fixed choice, we again have three cases.  If $0$ black cards are fixed then there are $!4$ ways to do it. If exactly one black card is fixed then there are $!3$ ways to do it for each choice of fixed black card, and if both black cards are fixed then there is only $1$ way to do it.  Thus $$P(Y=1)=3\times \frac {!4+2\times 3!+1}{5!}=\frac 7{20}$$

$Y=2\quad$  There are $3$ ways to choose the fixed pair of Hearts.  For a fixed choice, we again have three cases.  If $0$ black cards are fixed then there are $!3$ ways to do it.  If exactly one black card is fixed then there are $!2$ ways to do it for each choice of fixed black card.  If both black cards are fixed then there is no way to do it.  Thus $$P(Y=2)=3\times \frac {!3+2\times !2}{5!}=\frac 1{10}$$

$Y=3\quad$  In this case we either permute the two black cards or we fix them both, so $$P(Y=3)=\frac 2{5!}=\frac 1{60}$$

Sanity checks:  first of all, these must sum to $1$.  Indeed we get $$\frac {32+21+6+1}{60}=1$$

Secondly, it is easy to see that the expected number of fixed hearts is $\frac 35$ (hint: use indicator variables).  And it is easy to confirm that number directly from the probabilities.

Comment: Would i do a sanity check the same way for the joint probability ?

Comment: Sanity checks are always good,  though I don't know what sort of expected value you could compute.  If you look at the details of my computation, you'll see that the joint distribution is essentially written out.